# How to implement google directions API in Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, directions

I'm a beginner in the field of android and currently working on a cab app . In this app I need to implement Map and directions API, I went through couple of tutorials and got several APIs but i dont know how to draw the returned data on the map so guys please help.. need some guidance. Thank you

For the moment i've extracted the latlng of source and destination and have created a seperate MapActivity for showing directions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) gives you a polyline (a list of LatLng points to draw a nice curvy line) of the returned route in an [encoded format](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm?hl=en) in `"overview_polyline"` and `"polyline"` fields in the JSON it returns.

By decoding this data you can create a [`Polyline`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) object which is then drawn on the [`GoogleMap`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap). Writing your own decoder isn't too difficult, but there's also [android-maps-utils library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) that contains a method for this and many other fancy things you might want to use on Google Maps related things.

An example use of this library would be something like

```
GoogleMap map = ...;
String encodedPolyline = readFromJson();
Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
    .addAll(PolyUtil.decode(encodedPolyline))
    .width(5)
    .color(Color.RED));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but can you please tell me how can I continue further as i have latlng of source and destination

Comment: @ManishNegi do you mean how to ask the directions API about how to get from source coordinates to destination coordinates?

Comment: actullay i don't know what i need .. but what i want is i don't want to parse json and draw polyline manually.. is that possible?

Comment: @ManishNegi not really, there's no direct integration in Google Maps android API to the directions API, so you'll have to write the glue in between. You can easily parse JSON with a library like [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)